# Best design approach for creating Immutable Class

Tags: java, immutability, final

I am reading about the specific guidelines that needs to be followed while creating Immutable Class in [*Effective Java*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/bloch-effective-08-qa-140880.html).

I read that In Immutable class method should not allowed to be overridden otherwise overridden method may change the behaviour of method. Following are the design approaches available in java to solve this problem  :-

1. We can mark class final but as per my understanding, it has a one disadvantage that it makes the class inextensible.
2. Secondly is to make individual methods final but I can not get other disadvantage besides that we need to individually mark each method as final in order to prevent overridding.
3. As per book,better approach is to make the constructor private or package-private and provide public static factory method for creating object.

My question is: Even if we include private or default constructor in the class, it cannot be extended anymore in same package (in other package in case of package-private constructor), it has a same problem which the first one had. How is it considered as the better approach than the previous ones?

Comment: You certainly cannot allow an immutable class to be extended. This is one of the key requirements for a class to be immutable.

Comment: You can see examples for the approach making the constructor private in the primitive type's wrapper classes: `Integer`, `Double`, etc. When being immutable an object often is seen as a value. Thus it is not important whether the same value is represented by one object only or (potentially) by several objects. Therefore a static factory method is provided that might return the same object for the same value.

Comment: A final class e.g. `java.lang.String` is **`final`** and can neither be extended nor modified once instantiated.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The constructors of Integer, Double etc. are public.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ups! But the overall subject still holds true.

Comment: @Vinit89 your "disadvantage" is the _point_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a static factory method gives you room to implement the Flyweight Pattern.

They're stating that you should hide the possibility of creating a new object using a constructor, and should rather make a call to a method which checks if an object with similar state exists in the "object pool" (a map filled with objects waiting to be re-used). Not re-using immutable objects is a waste of memory; this is why `String` literals are encouraged, and `new String()` is shunned (unless needed).

```
class ImmutableType {
    private static final Map<Definition, ImmutableType> POOL = new HashMap<>();

    private final Definition definition;

    private ImmutableType(Definition def) {
         definition = def;
    }

    public static ImmutableType get(Definition def) {
         if(POOL.contains(def))
              return POOL.get(def);
        else {
              ImmutableType obj = new ImmutableType(def);
              POOL.put(def, obj);

              return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

`Definition` stores the state of the `ImmutableType`. If a type with the same definition already exists in the pool, then re-use it. Otherwise, create it, add it to the pool then return it as the value.

As for the statement about marking the class `final`, immutable types should not be extensible in the first place (to avoid possibly modifying behavior). Marking every method `final` is just crazy for immutable classes.

Answer (score 3):

An immutable object should not be extensible. Why?

Because extending it will allow either direct access to fields (if they are `protected` which would allow writing methods that change them), or adding state which may be mutable.

Imagine we wrote a class `FlexiblyRoundableDouble` that extends `Double`, which has an additional field `roundingMode` that lets us choose a "rounding mode". You could write a setter for this field, and now your object is mutable.

You can argue that if all the methods are set as final, you cannot change the original behavior of the object. The only methods that could access your `roundingMode` field are new methods that are not polymorphically available if you assign your object to a `Double` variable. But when a class's contract says that it's immutable, you make decisions based on that. For example, if you write a `clone()` method or copy constructor for a class that has `Double` fields, you know that you don't need to deep-copy the `Double` fields, as they do not change their state, and can therefore be safely shared between the two clones.

Also, you can write methods that return the internal object without fearing that the caller will then change that object. If the object was mutable, you'd have to make a "defensive copy" of it. But if it's immutable, it's safe to return a reference to the actual internal object.

However, what happens if someone assigned a `FlexiblyRoundableDouble` to one of your `Double` fields? That object would be mutable. The `clone()` would assume it isn't, it will be shared between two objects, perhaps even returned by a method. The caller would then be able to cast it back as a `FlexiblyRoundableDouble`, change the field... and it will affect other objects that use that same instance.

Therefore, immutable objects should be final.

---

All this has nothing to do with the constructor issue. Objects can be safely immutable with public constructors (as demonstrated by `String`, `Double`, `Integer` and other standard Java immutables). The static factory method is simply a way *utilizing* the fact that the object is immutable, and several other objects can hold references to it safely, to create fewer objects with the same value.